# Does FreeRTOS support C11 and its features?

Tags: c, c11, freertos

I am writing a new application with FreeRTOS, and I figured a new application shouldn't be limited to older dialects of C. So I thought why not use C11 with FreeRTOS?

Does FreeRTOS support C11 and its new features? In particular, I'm wondering about the support for the new threading libraries and headers. How does this work, given that FreeRTOS is the kernel that manages all this? I couldn't really find an answer to this online, hence asking here...

Comment: If it provides an API, why not?

Comment: @0andriy: I don't know about FreeRTOS in particular, but some embedded operating systems only support one 32-bit thread-local object.  If a C11 implementation were to combine all thread-local objects into a structure, and then use the one OS-supported 32-bit object to hold a pointer to the thread-local-object structure, then the fact that the OS only supports one thread-local object wouldn't be a problem.  I don't know if any C11 implementations work that way, however.